# .length -1 vs. .length in a JavaScript loop

Tags: javascript, loops

I created a function to demonstrate how to reverse a string:

```
 var reverseString = function(str) {

        var reverseStr = '';

        for (var i = str.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            reverseStr += str[i];
        }

        return reverseStr;
 };

reverseString('javaScript'); //returns "tpircSavaj"
```

As I was going through each line to understand what was going on, I was soon bewildered by this part:

```
        for (var i = str.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
```

Wouldn't using `str.length` make more sense as your are starting from the last position in the string. In this case `t`?

Is the reason why you'd start at `-1` vs. `.length` is because when you get to `j` using `.length` it is going to foul up the loop. I can picture it but can't articulate it properly.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Step through the code in a debugger to see what happens.

Comment: The length returns the actual length, however as arrays are zero-based most people subtract one from the length so they match up.

Comment: sidenote `mystring.split("").reverse().join("")` to reverse a string

Comment: Side note: When reversing a string manually, you only have to loop through half of it and swap the characters

Comment: @RaymondChen: Ahh—I forgot to do that...Always a good tool!

Comment: @SlashmanX, strings are immutable.

Comment: @Qwertiy Not after splitting though. (I was adding on to the comment above mine but pointing towards a more 'manual' method)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's basically because the first position of a string is 0, is zero based. I'll give you an example:

```
var s = 'a';
```

the length of s is 1. but s[1] is undefined. However s[0] is equal to 'a'.

Comment: OHHHH—So in my case when the loop starts, we used `str.length` for the value of `i`, And since we count strings from position `0`— when we pass the value of `i`, it's `10` (because that's the length of  the `javaScript` string), so the first value `undefined` is what gets appended to `reverseStr`, because we'd be passing essentially`str[10]`?

Comment: if the length of you string is `10` then `str[10]` will be undefined. the last position of you string will be `str.length - 1` which in this case will be `9`

Comment: So my rational was sound?

Comment: you were right, I was just clarifying. Sorry for not being clear

Comment: Not at all! Thanks so much—It was your adroit example which got me to understand!

Answer (score 0):

That's because the length starts count from 1, but when accessing to string first element you need to start from 0, like you do in arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, to complement the answers above, another way of looking at it is:

- `array.length` returns an integer with the amount of elements contained in the array
- `array.length - 1` returns the index of the last item in the array

Here is an example:
`const arr = ["A", "B", "C"]`

Quantity of elements in the array
`console.log(arr.length) // Output: 3`

The index of the last position of the array
`console.log(arr.length - 1) // Output: 2`